# Java - How to split array on each iteration and pass into a function efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array that holds some values and a function that takes in two arrays. What I want to do is split the array so that the last element is not in the array so I have two arrays, one that has all the original elements except the last and one that has just one element - the last. After I pass this into a function, I want to use the original array but this time put the second last element into a seperate array and so on. I want to do this five times. The following will explain it better:

```
int[] val = {25,50,66,75,100,1000,5000,10000,25000};

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

//Need to split the array and then pass it to the function here
}

public void evaluate(int[] train, int[] test){

....
}
```

So for example in the first iteration I want to remove/split 25000 from the array and put it into another array and then pass the two arrays throught the function:

first array now has `{25,50,66,75,100,1000,5000,10000}`
and second array now has `{25000}`

On next iteration I want to now split/remove 10000 (25000 is now back in the array):

so first array now has `{25,50,66,75,100,1000,5000,25000}`
and second array now has `{10000}`

So basically it is going from the bottom and working its way up, but only 5 times.

Comment: Please don't include "Im sorry if I cant explain this properly (hence the long description). Hope someone can help or point me in the right direction. Thanks" in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: @Doorknob wow ok. Was being polite, thanks anyway

Comment: I know, that's what I thought in the beginning too. However, it is generally frowned upon here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Maybe use LinkedList, use `remove(int index)`, `add(int index, E element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the two arrays up front, and swap one element into your test array after each iteration. This will be faster than allocating new arrays all the time.

```
int[] val = {25,50,66,75,100,1000,5000,10000,25000};

// create the destination arrays:
int[] train = new int[val.length-1];
int[] test = new int[1];

// initialize the arrays:
test[0] = val[val.length-1];
for (int i = 0; i < val.length-1; ++i)
{
    train[i] = val[i];
}

int timesToIterate = 5;

for (int iteration = 0; iteration < timesToIterate; ++iteration)
{
    evaluate(train, test);

    int i = train.length-1-iteration;
    if (i >= 0) // don't swap if this is the last element in the array
    {
        int tmp = test[0];
        test[0] = train[i];
        train[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

With your example data, the arrays passed into the evaluate function are:

```
{25 50 66 75 100 1000 5000 10000 } {25000}
{25 50 66 75 100 1000 5000 25000 } {10000}
{25 50 66 75 100 1000 10000 25000 } {5000}
{25 50 66 75 100 5000 10000 25000 } {1000}
{25 50 66 75 1000 5000 10000 25000 } {100}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to switch from using arrays to using a `List<Integer>`. You can then use the `subList` method to construct arrays that are subsequences of the original array.

If you insist on using arrays, you have two options:

1. Add arguments to represent the start and end index of the applicable range for each array argument. You then need to rewrite your logic to go from start through end-1 (instead of 0 through array.length - 1).
2. Allocate new arrays and copy the data into them. This won't work if you intend to modify the array elements and in any case is a lot of extra work.

Here's some code to show how to use a `List<Integer>`:

```
// autobox each value as an Integer:
List<Integer> vals = Arrays.asList(
    new Integer[] {25,50,66,75,100,1000,5000,10000,25000});
final int len = vals.length();

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    evaluate(vals.subList(0, i), vals.subList(i, len));
}

public void evaluate(List<Integer> train, List<Integer> test){

....
}
```

Comment: The values that get passed to the function will never get modified so in the end, the original array values will still stay intact

Comment: @Matt9Atkins - I would still recommend using a `List` of some kind. I added some sample code to show what I have in mind.

Comment: I have contemplated using a list of some kind but my function needs to use an array. So I can do the splits and convert back into an array and then pass to the function, but that will be overkill

Comment: @Matt9Atkins - Well, then the option of passing the range start and end index for each array may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

check out the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) API you can do it with the Arrays.copyOf(..) method.

```
newArray = Arrays.copyOf(oldArray, oldArray.length-1)
```

Perhaps this code can help you you.

```
    int[] val = { 25, 50, 66, 75, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000 };
    int[] firstArray = new int[val.length-1];
    int[] SecondArray = new int[1];     
    //iterates the whole array set to 5 if needed
    for (int n = 0; n < val.length; n++) {
        SecondArray[0] = val[val.length-n-1];
        for(int x = 0, firstArrayCounter= 0; x < val.length; x++){
            if(val[x]!=SecondArray[0]){                 
                firstArray[firstArrayCounter] = val[x];
                firstArrayCounter++;
            }       
        }
        //prints what is in the arrays                      
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++)
            System.out.print(firstArray[i] + " ");
        System.out.println("\n"+SecondArray[0]);
    }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I dunno what you are trying to do in the end but this seems to be a perfect fit for a functional programing language. Anyway we can do it in java and moreover with arrays :

In you for loop that's going from 1 to 5 included you might put something like :

```
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
  int[] train = new int[val.length-i];
  System.arraycopy( val, 0, train, 0, train.length-1 );
  int test = new int[1];
  test[0] = val[val.length-i];
  evaluate(train,test);
}
```

Comment: The length of train array will never decrease. It will just remove an element and add the previously removed one back in

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm I would use is:

1. Take the original array, A, and create a new A' with 1 less element and a single-element array, call it B.
2. Populate A' with n-1 elements, populate B with 1 element.
3. Then, when you've completed processing A' and B, swap the appropriate element in A' with B[0].

The single copy is `O(n)` and each of the 5 iterations has a constant time operation to do the swap. Memory is also `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayUtils of Apache commons, code example is like as follows:

```
    private static int[] val = { 25, 50, 66, 75, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000 };
    private static int[] test = {};

    public static void evaluate(int[] train, int[] test) {
        for (int i = 0; i < train.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(train[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(test[i] + ",");

        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(test))
                ArrayUtils.remove(test, 0);
            evaluate(ArrayUtils.remove(val, val.length - 1 - i), ArrayUtils.add(test, val[val.length - 1 - i]));
        }
    }
```